# Python that checks dates with date on file

Tags: python

Making a custom command for Splunk. Trying to match today date with Federal holiday on another python file. Have my Holiday file imported to the python file I am writing but can't get today date to look if at the file to see if it's a holiday.

Python code

```
import Holiday_List # This is the list of dates for US holidays
import datetime # importing datetime module


file = open("Holiday_List.py",'r') # open the Holiday List

content = Holiday_List()

matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(content)) 
now = datetime()

if now = file  
    
    print("It's a Holiday")

else
    print("no Holiday")
```

Comment: You don't seem to be trying. The code you've posted won't run because it contains errors. Another question is why do you both import Holiday_List and read it as a file? Where does datefinder come from?

Comment: `open()` returns a file handle, not the contents of the file. You set `now = datetime()` - what do you think this means? It does not create a datetime object representing the current time. Even if you fixed these two issues, `if now = file` wouldn't work because 1. you can't compare a datetime to a string, and 2. you aren't comparing anything at all - `a = b` assigns `b` to `a`. What is `Holiday_List`? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Python as well but this worked for me, assuming your modules work correctly

```
if now in matches:
    print("It's a Holiday")
else:
    print("no Holiday")
```

reference: https://geeksforgeeks.org/python-holidays-library/